# qgis getFeautures function on filtered selection

Tags: python, qgis

i have this little script

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LAYERNAME")[0]
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    if feat ['FILTER1'] == 24 and feat ['FILTER2'] == 'AFUMEX' and feat ['FILTER3'] == 'SOTTERRANEO':
        a= (feat['FEATUREtoBEsummed'])
        print(a)
```

which returns:

```
>>>33
>>>40
>>>30
>>>61
>>>91
>>>115
>>>47
```

i can't figure out how to sum all the numbers that this script returns.
i've tried with

```
sum(a)
```

and

```
sum(feat('FEATUREtoBEsummed'))
```

i've also tried to conver the variable 'a' in a list but the list is basically many list with the splitted values such as

```
>>>['3', '3']
>>>['4', '0']
>>>['3', '0']
>>>['6', '1']
>>>['9', '1']
>>>['1', '1', '5']
>>>['4', '7']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LAYERNAME")[0]
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
if feat ['FILTER1'] == 24 and feat ['FILTER2'] == 'AFUMEX' and feat['FILTER3'] == 'SOTTERRANEO':
    a+= (feat['FEATUREtoBEsummed'])
print(a)
```

Comment: i get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'type' and 'int'
i've tried with:
`layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("CAVI")[0]
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    if feat ['POT_CAVO'] == 24 and feat ['filter1'] == 'AFUMEX':
        a += int(feat['FEATUREtoBEsummed'])`

Comment: Suppose you have this list a = [['3', '3'], ['4', '0'],['3', '0'],['6', '1'],['9', '1'],['1', '1', '5'],['4', '7']] (if not could you provide the list?). Try this code : 
`val = 0                                                                                                                             for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        val += (float(a[i][j]))
print(val)`

Answer (score 0):

i've figured out my error.
i was entering the initial variable sum= 0 inside the for loop so it was turned to 0 at every iteration :
correct code is:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("NAME")[0]
sum = 0 
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    if feat ['FILTER1'] == 24 and feat ['FILTER2'] == 'AFUMEX' :
        a = int((feat['FEATtoBEsummed']))
        sum = sum + a
        print(a)
print ('tot=', sum)
```